# Is it possible to display html formatted text in antd table?

Tags: reactjs, antd

My backend service(elasticsearch percolator) annotates text with html tags to highlight matches.

I can't find a way to display such html data in antd Table.

I've tried Highlighter component, but it applies keywords to whole column, but I need to highlight different words in each row.

[link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mindis/j36gysxc/)

```
const { Table } = antd

class TableColor extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        data: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        data: [
        {id:1, name: 'Lazy < bclass="myBackgroundColor">fox</b>', match: 'fox'},
        {id:2, name: '<b class="myBackgroundColor">Dog</b> runs', match: 'Dog'},
        {id:3, name: 'I saw <b class="myBackgroundColor">duck</b>', match: 'duck'}
      ]
    })
  }

  render () {
   const columns = [{
      title: 'ID',
      dataIndex: 'id',
    }, {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
    }, {
      title: 'Match',
      dataIndex: 'match',
    }]

    return (
        <div style={{padding: '20px'}}>
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={this.state.data}
        />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TableColor />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it looks like the `name` column already has highlighted html you could just add a `render` property to the `name` column definition that uses `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` to render the raw html.

...something like:

`render: function(html) { return <div dangerouslySetInnerHtml({__html: html}) />`

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml
https://ant.design/components/table/#Column

If you wanted to use react-highlight-words you could do the same thing with a render property but use the second argument passed to that function to get the `.match` property of the record and use that as the highlighted word.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use dangerouslySetInnerHTML in render function like:

```
render: (html:any) => {return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />}
```